# Mysql "like"-query gets no results, but it should

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update, where-clause

I have a table like this:

```
jobunique  | jobtitle | joblat | joblng
1          | kellner  | 20     | 40
```

In `phpMyAdmin` I tried to make this query:

```
SELECT jobunique, joblat, joblng FROM job WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%kell%'
```

But the query gives me no results. If I delete the LIKE-statement it works, but the syntax seems to be right. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

With this query I get the result:

```
SELECT jobunique, joblat, joblng FROM job WHERE jobtitle LIKE '%ell%'
```

But on w3schools.com is written:

`WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'`    Finds any values that have `"or"` in **any position**

- Now, my question is how do i get the result if the first letter of the word is there?

Comment: Syntax looks correct. May be double check your table name, data in column "jobtitle", ensure that the query runs in MySQL first and then check in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: `%kell%` will always match `kellner`. It is likely that the content of your column is not `kellner`. Try `update job set jobtitle = 'kellner' where jobunique = 1`, then rerun your `select`.

Comment: Ah, im sorry. I made a mistake. It´s "Kellner". I did not know that large and lower case mathers. Is there a way to ignore that within a mysql-query or do I have to find a solution with php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%kell%` will always match `kellner`. It is almost certain that the content of your column is not `kellner`.

Try :

```
update job set jobtitle = 'kellner' where jobunique = 1
```

Then rerun your select.

You could also make the search case-insensitive using [mysql `LOWER()` function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lower-function.php) :

```
SELECT jobunique, joblat, joblng FROM job WHERE LOWER(jobtitle) LIKE '%kell%'
```